# Mediawiki: Uploading tables of extension via browser

Tags: mediawiki

How do I update the wiki database with the tables of the newly installed extensions? I read [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Web_browser) and went to **mywiki.com/mw-config/** and got a page for upgrading the entire wiki instead of updating the tables. Is this the right way to do it? Is there a chance of losing all the data and user information of my wiki if I do this? Please suggest me a way.

Comment: Backup the database;  Then you don't have to worry about losing data.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have the database backup but I want to know whether this is the right way to do it..

Comment: If you have a backup.  Then it doesn't matter if its the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Your comments are not helping...

Comment: Alright;  We will try this another way.  What part of the upgrade process are you specifically confused about.  I read the process, actually the entire manual for Mediawiki, and the process seems straight forward.  You should place the database in readonly mode, do a backup, then perform the upgrade.  If you cannot clarify what exactly you are confused about, I will be forced to vote your question, as not being helpful to the community as a whole.

Comment: @Ramhound : As i mentioned in my question I am confused about "how the tables of extensions should be added to the database?". Is "UPGRADIING THE ENTIRE WIKI" the only possible way to do it? Is there any other method?

Comment: Why are you against doing an upgrade on your installation?  Just follow the installation directions for the extensions.  If you want to provide an example of one of your extensions I can research that.

Answer (score 0):

`php maintenance/update.php`

That's it.

Note, upgrading your MediaWiki code is advisable. A very outdated MediaWiki version puts your data at higher risk than the upgrade process (if done following [instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Upgrading)).

However, just running the web updater will *not* upgrade your code: newer code has to be downloaded by yourself (or by your package manager).